# Slide show shows 2 pictures at a time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make slide show with a transition through transparency, but the problem is when I have 4 images and 4th image changing with 1st, 1st image probably somehow show early and push 3rd image down. Another problem is when 3rd image changing with 4th, 4th image does not create some free space under him like all others (In case of bad resolution it may not be visible). This problem occurs also when I add more than 4 images and always only on the last picture. Any suggestions how to fix it and what I do wrong?

```js
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.imageSlide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

function nextSlide() {
  slides[currentSlide].className = "imageSlide";
  currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
  slides[currentSlide].className = "imageSlide showing";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imageSlide-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.imageSlide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1.0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 1.0s;
  transition: opacity 1.0s;
}

.showing {
  position: static;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.prev,
.next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="imageSlide-container">
  <img class="imageSlide showing" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_nature_wide.jpg">
  <img class="imageSlide" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg">
  <img class="imageSlide" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_mountains_wide.jpg">
  <img class="imageSlide" src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords_wide.jpg">

  <span class="prev" onclick="plusSlide-button(-1)">&#10094;</span>
  <span class="next" onclick="plusSlide-button(1)">&#10095;</span>
</div>
<a>test text</a>
<a>test text</a>
<a>test text</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use `position: absolute` **and** `position: static` for one item.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
}

.showing {
  position: static;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item showing">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

That's the reason why you get this weird behaviour. Every item must be on top.

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Respectively

```
.imageSlide {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    ...
}
```